# Expectation of Brownian motion increments under a permutation.

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Tl;dr, here is my question. Let
$$\gamma(x):=\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$
denote the standard Gaussian density, fix an integer $n\in\mathbb N$, and let $(B_t)_{t\geq0}$ denote a standard Brownian motion. Given any permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ on $n$ symbols, does it hold that
\begin{align*}
E[\gamma(B_{\sigma(1)})\gamma(B_{\sigma(2)}-B_{\sigma(1)})\cdots\gamma(B_{\sigma(n)}-B_{\sigma(n-1)})]
&\leq E[\gamma(B_1)\gamma(B_2-B_1)\cdots\gamma(B_n-B_{n-1})]\\
&=E[\gamma(B_1)]^n?\tag{1}
\end{align*}

---

My reason for asking is the comparison of the two following computations. One the one hand, consider the integral
$$I=\int_{\mathbb R^n}\left(\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\gamma(x_{\sigma(1)})\gamma(x_{\sigma(2)}-x_{\sigma(1)})\cdots\gamma(x_{\sigma(n)}-x_{\sigma(n-1)})\right)^2~d x_1\cdots dx_n,$$
where $S_n$ denotes the symmetric group of permutations on $n$ symbols.

By Jensen's inequality, we have
$$I\leq n!\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\gamma(x_{\sigma(1)})^2\gamma(x_{\sigma(2)}-x_{\sigma(1)})^2\cdots\gamma(x_{\sigma(n)}-x_{\sigma(n-1)})^2~d x_1\cdots dx_n,$$
which, up to relabeling the $x_i$ variables, gives
$$I\leq (n!)^2\int_{\mathbb R^n}\gamma(x_{1})^2\gamma(x_{2}-x_{1})^2\cdots\gamma(x_{n}-x_{n-1})^2~d x_1\cdots dx_n.$$
Then,
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb R^n}\gamma(x_{1})^2\gamma(x_{2}-x_{1})^2\cdots\gamma(x_{n}-x_{n-1})^2~d x_1\cdots dx_n
&=E[\gamma(B_1)\gamma(B_2-B_1)\cdots\gamma(B_n-B_{n-1})]\\
&=E[\gamma(B_1)]^n,\end{align*}
so we conclude that
$$I\leq(n!)^2E[\gamma(B_1)].\tag{2}$$

---

On the other hand,  if we expand the square in $I$ directly, up to a relabeling of indices, we get
\begin{align*}
I&=n!\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\prod_{k=1}^n\gamma(x_k-x_{k-1})\gamma(x_{\sigma(k)}-x_{\sigma(k-1)})~d x_1\cdots dx_n\\
&=n!\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}E[\gamma(B_{\sigma(1)})\gamma(B_{\sigma(2)}-B_{\sigma(1)})\cdots\gamma(B_{\sigma(n)}-B_{\sigma(n-1)})].
\end{align*}
Comparing this with inequality $(2)$, this suggests that $(1)$ might be true, but I have no probabilistic intuition/explanation for why this should or should not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact true, and follows from the following more general claim.

> Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with determinant $|A|=1$. If $G=(G_1,\ldots,G_n)$ is a standard Gaussian vector, then
>   $$(2\pi)^{-n/2}E[e^{-\|A G\|^2/2}]\leq (2\pi)^{-n/2}E[e^{-\|G\|^2/2}].$$

Indeed, by a simple application of Cauchy-Schwarz and a change of variables,
\begin{align}
(2\pi)^{-n/2}E[e^{-\|A G\|^2/2}]&=\int\frac{e^{-\|Ax\|^2/2}}{(2\pi)^{-n/2}}\frac{e^{-\|x\|^2/2}}{(2\pi)^{-n/2}}~dx\\
&\leq\left(\int\frac{e^{-\|Ax\|^2}}{(2\pi)^{-n}}~d x\right)^{1/2}\left(\int\frac{e^{-\|x\|^2}}{(2\pi)^{-n}}~dx\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\int\frac{e^{-\|x\|^2}}{(2\pi)^{-n}}~d x\right)^{1/2}\left(\int\frac{e^{-\|x\|^2}}{(2\pi)^{-n}}~dx\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\int\frac{e^{-\|x\|^2/2}}{(2\pi)^{-n/2}}\frac{e^{-\|x\|^2/2}}{(2\pi)^{-n/2}}~dx\\
&=(2\pi)^{-n/2}E[e^{-\|G\|^2/2}].
\end{align}